# Concavity of a function - issue

Tags: functions, derivatives

I've a trouble in an economic application. Let me put the question in the simplest way by avoiding any economic content.

Consider the following function $g(x)$, with $g'(x)>0$ and $g''(x)<0$, where $g: R_{+} \mapsto R_{+}$.

Then, with $x^\ast$ being the unique fixpoint of $g(.)$, why $\frac{g'(x^\ast)x^\ast}{g(x^\ast)}$ defines the degree of concavity of  $g(x)$?

Comment: If $x^*$ is a fixed point of $g$ then $g(x^*) = x^*$ and the fraction you've written is just the derivative at the point where the graph crosses the line $y=x$. Have I interpreted the question correctly? Is this helpful? Please [edit] the question to clarify - discussions in comments are frowned on.

Comment: What you interpreted is correct mathematically. What I'm asking (and this exactly what I wrote above) is why the derivative of a function evaluated at a fixpoint times the fixpoint itself divided by the function evaluated at the fixpoint defines the degree of concavity of $g(.)$